# Best convention for using ARGV with class in Ruby

Tags: ruby

- situation

I'm learning Ruby's class and constant now.

I thought example code for my class, and decide to make class for practice.

I will use ARGV for argument of my script.

But i'm wondering for right convention for using ARGV with class.

My question is,

1. Where should i place my code which access to ARGV? I thought several example for structure. (A and B)
   Which one is better for convention?
2. Is this right convention for using ARGV inside of class like example A?

- A

```
class ExampleClass
  CONSTANT = ARGV[0]

  def example_function
    puts CONSTANT
  end
end

ex = ExampleClass.new
ex.example_function
```

- B

```
class ExampleClass
  def example_function
    puts CONSTANT
  end
end

CONSTANT = ARGV[0]
ex = ExampleClass.new
ex.example_function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do:

```
class ExampleClass
  def initialize(args)
    @args = args
  end

  def example_function
    @args
  end
end

ex = ExampleClass.new(ARGV[0])
ex.example_function
```

Comment: i fixed my question a little, using inside of class is bad convention?

Comment: I would consider using `ARGV` in a class a code smell. But that is just my opinion.

Comment: thanks a lot. If i need to use ten variable of ARGV like ARGV[0], ARGV[1], ARGV[2]...   passing ARGV to .new method's argument and parse inside of initialize  method is good ways? ```ex = ExampleClass.new(ARGV)``` and ``` def initialize(args)
    @args1 = args[0]
    @args2 = args[1] .....
  end```

Comment: I’d suggest enclosing the “main” portion of the script in a `if $PROGRAM_NAME == __FILE__` … `end` block, since a well-designed class or module could be useful as a reusable utility for other scripts at some point in the future.